# getting ruby enumerable (.select,.min,.max) as a reference rather than a copy

Tags: ruby, arrays, pointers, hash

I'm doing a whole bunch of stuff with an array of hashes, and learning a ton.

I am trying to loop through the array and change some of the values, and remove some, etc. etc.

I think that because I'm using things like

```
    find_best = original_array.select{|h| h[:score]>15}
```

I'm ending up with a new array of the matches, rather than a bunch of pointers to the original array.

So when I say (as example)

```
   find_best.each do |something|
            #manipulate somehow
   end
```

Those changes are not reflected in the `original_array`.

I guess I could `merge` the `find_best` into the `original_array`, though I'm not entirely sure how to do that, or if that is the right thing to do.

The biggest problem I run into is when I say

```
 while find_best.length>0
       #do some stuff that recalculates find_best
        find_best = original_array.select{|h| h[:score]>15} #so I'm resetting the loop for find_best and exit if all the work is done. 
 end
```

Comment: What's the question? `select`, `map` and the alikes just create a new array with references to the original items in the old array. What's the problem? Why not just do `best = best.select { |h| h[:score] > 15 }` or even `best.select! { |h| h[:score] > 15 }`? By the way, if you change `something` inside that loop, the changes should affect the object also referenced by the original array.

Comment: @Niklas, hhmmmm I'm seeing different behaviour here. I'm updating values in the hashes, but when I print out the original array, I'm not seeing the updates.

Comment: That's seems very unlikely (and would be a Ruby bug). Please include minimal code that really shows the issue. [Demo](http://ideone.com/Ez2oP).

Comment: you are correct @NiklasB., sorry for the confusion. I had an error in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Niklas already noted in the comment, `select`, `map` and alike create new arrays, but they contain the very objects from the original array, not their copies.

Observe:

```
a = [{foo: 1, bar: 'a'}, {foo: 3, bar: 'b'}, {foo: 2, bar: 'c'}]
#=> [{:foo=>1, :bar=>"a"}, {:foo=>3, :bar=>"b"}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>"c"}]
a.max_by{|e| e[:foo]}[:bar] = 'GOTCHA!'
a
#=> [{:foo=>1, :bar=>"a"}, {:foo=>3, :bar=>"GOTCHA!"}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>"c"}]
```

See? A member of the original array was modified.

Comment: If you allow, I'll just stick my [demo](http://ideone.com/Ez2oP) link here, in case someone is still not convinced :)

Comment: Oh sure, and sorry as I was only restating what you already wrote.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is Ruby's `delete_if` or `delete` enum.

Here's a sample:

```
ruby > jasdeep = {:a => 123, :b => 999, :c => 1, :d => 12, :e => 6}
 => {:a=>123, :b=>999, :c=>1, :d=>12, :e=>6} 
ruby > jasdeep.class
 => Hash 
ruby > jasdeep.delete_if {|key, val| val < 15 }
 => {:a=>123, :b=>999} 
ruby > jasdeep
 => {:a=>123, :b=>999}
```

Here, we are modifying the original Hash, I hope that solves your question.

Comment: Something to really look out for when doing these type of iterations is that if your iteration modifies your values in the Hash - Then your block can blow up on you... It's better to resort to safe change methods...